# .onClick() function is calling when the page loads?

Tags: jquery

I want to call the onClick() function only when the related button is clicked. But when i put a debug point in VS2012, I see that this function is calling when the page loads. Is there any method to pretend from this?

```
 $("#BtnAcik@(OppDetail.ID)").click(function () {                 
    @{
    var RevenuePlan = OppDetail.CRM_REVENUE_PLAN;
    var TotalNewRev = RevenuePlan.Sum(c => c.AMOUNT);
    var SolutionPlan = OppDetail.CRM_SOLUTION_DISTRIBUTION;
    var TotalSol = SolutionPlan.Sum(c => c.AMOUNT);
    if (TotalNewRev == TotalSol){
       <text>
       bootbox.confirm("Eminmisiniz?", function (result) {                   
           if (result === true) {
               window.location = '/opp/ChangeStatusToAcik?OppDetailId=@(OppDetail.ID)';
           } else {

           }

       });
    </text>
    } else{ 
        <text>
        bootbox.alert("Çözüm plani toplami ile gelir plani toplami birbirine esit degil");
        </text>
    }
    } 
});
```

Comment: What do the `@` signs do?

Comment: Could you post the *generated* code? That would be more useful.

Comment: @RocketHazmat It's asp.net Razor syntax. C# code snippets like `<?php echo OppDetail.ID ?>`

Comment: Yes this is Razor Syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I want to call the onClick() function only when the related button is clicked. But when i put a debug point in VS2012, I see that this
>   function is calling when the page loads.*

When you put that breakpoint in there and get stopped on the server, you are breaking during the **rendering** of the page. Of course that happens on the server, before the page is even passed to the client where javascript can execute.

If you have server-side code that you need to execute after the page has loaded, you'll need to do a postback or an ajax call.

If you want to see when the actual javascript click handler executes, put a breakpoint in the script in the dev tools in your browser.

Comment: So it means, it is imposibble without using AJAX or PostBack, right ?

Comment: It is impossible for javascript to interact directly with server-side code. You could restructure so the function is executed and all the data is available to javascript when the page loads, or you'll need to do an ajax call or postback.